# Jquery change div background picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this attribute

```
<div class="idfake" style="  background-image: url('images/ad.jpg')";>
```

I want to get the value of "style" which is images/ad.jpg

Using JQuery  I tried this

```
$('.idfake').attr('style', e.target.result);
```

Doesn't work.
I'm doing this so I can change background picture of the div...this is my code

```
<script>
        //change card background pic
        function readURLx(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.idfake').attr('style', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
          $("#logopic12").change(function(){
            readURLx(this);
        });
</script>

<input   accept="image/*" id="logopic12"  class="changebg" type="file" name="logo">
```

Comment: Are you trying to get or set the value?

Comment: you are looking for  $('.idfake').css("background-image") I think

Comment: im trying to change the background pic of the div  using jquery

Comment: So reconsider to reformule your question because this is completly unclear...

Comment: ok i changed the question...and  @Bindrid i tried it didnt work

Comment: i dont think it should be css..cauz the style is in the attribute.. <div class="idfake" style="  background-image: url('images/ad.jpg')";>

Comment: i think you can not use the e.target.result or anything from that proceed, cause of path returned by an input file is masked by the fakepath....
Your issue is very bad explained.... tell us the context of your code! and may be we can help you

Comment: ok is there another way to do that?

Comment: what is the sense of this code ? wanna explicitly use an img selected from an explorer dialog box, or just using having the choice of different background-image using css classes ???

Comment: well the user upload a picture and it automaticly be set as the div background  picture of div class"idfake"

Comment: ok, but this background must be persistant after refresh ?
(i dont think can we talking about an upload in regards of your code, its for an nodejs app ? or pure webapp ?)

Comment: nah my friend i just save it as a picture in the rest of the code id idnt put it sorry.,thanks so much for the help guys i got it solved check the answer bellow

Comment: ahh ok understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
        //change card background pic
        function readURLx(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.idfake').css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
          $("#logopic12").change(function(){
            readURLx(this);
        });
</script>

<input   accept="image/*" id="logopic12"  class="changebg" type="file" name="logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this alternative with an img background

```
<img src="blank.png" id="idfake" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:-1;">

  $(document).on("ready", function()
  {
    $("#logopic12").change(function()
    {
        console.log($(this)[0].files[0]);
        $("#idfake").attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL($(this)[0].files[0]));
    });
  })
```

Comment: yup with an image work too ,idk why i didnt think of this..thanks

Comment: yes, but your method is more elegent, and z-index is not required !